# Practical ways to increase Mental alertness?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, cognitive-neuroscience, personality

Are there any scientifically proven exercises which can improve mental alertness and awareness naturally? please share!

Answer (score 0):

I've heard many times all the benefits to Meditaion and Hypnosis, to which I can immediately propose those as methods in this scenario towards improving mental focus. You can check out this article https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/you-illuminated/201204/brain-scans-show-how-meditation-improves-mental-focus which talks about that very thing.